# Servlet Validation to Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, jsp, servlets

how can i pass value from servlet to javascript??

Comment: is there any effort from your side?

Comment: hope this link will help for you http://www.java4s.com/ajax/checking-user-name-availability-with-ajax-google-style/

Answer (score 7):

The easiest and best way is to declare "empid" as unique in the database table. This way SQL SERVER will take care of the uniqueness of the column.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_employee
( 
  EmpID INT NOT NULL,
  EmpName VARCHAR(20)
  PRIMARY KEY (EmpID)
)
```

Hope it'll help you.